# google maps overlay layer

Tags: css, google-maps

i'm trying to put a layer on top of my google maps to cover it up. There doesn't have to be any interaction with google maps, it's just one layer on top the other.

what i have now:

```
<div id="map">
   <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

in the map div i put my google maps, and the overlay layer has a background as big as the map div, but the google maps keeps putting itself on top.

Anyone an idee what i can do about it?

Comment: did you try playing with z-index?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The API will overwrite anything inside the DIV you assign to the map as container.
To cover the map you'd need to put your overlay div outside the map div with position:absolute

Comment: That answer is from Aug 4 2010. Google have added the noClear option since then. Thanks for the down-vote.

Answer (score 11):

Google Maps API V3 supports an option called [`noClear`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions):

> If true, do not clear the contents of the Map div.

Use it like:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  noClear: true,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
```

However, semantically it feels better to put the div#overlay as the next sibling of the map div as @Marcelo suggests.

Comment: +1, this solution helped me a lot, as the `div` remains within the `map` bounds, thanx alot.