# Mysterious invisible paragraph tag

Tags: css

For some reason, a paragraph tag isn't being shown on my page and I can't figure out why.

The paragraph in question is in the #modules div, at the bottom of the map.

http://www.nickythorne.com/projects/Personal/education.php

Many Thanks.

Comment: idk... but adding position:absolute to it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Try position:absolute on your #modules div.

Check out this other SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405603/google-maps-overlay-layer)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS for for id `education` has a height of 600 while the maps id `glamorgan` has a height of 100% and with float it is filling up the education div with the map while pushing the modules div below out of sight in the education div, you can probably simple remove the `float` property on `glamorgan` or change the height of `glamorgan` to a fixed size to make room for the modules div.

It really all depends on what else your trying to accomplish on the page with the modules.